# How to improve NiFi performance

Tags: multithreading, memory-management, apache-nifi, opc-ua

i have an issue regrading the performances of Apache NiFi. I'm running an OPCSubscriber that send 20000 fileflows per second to Apache Kafka. The Nifi server crashes for no reason.

I solved partially this problem by increasing the JVM memory in boostrap configuration:

```
# JVM memory settings
java.arg.2=-Xms6g
java.arg.3=-Xmx6g
```

As well as increasing the allocated threads for publishkafka process from 1 to 1024 threads. But still, i can't ingest in high throughput since the size of queue keep increasing.

The server requirements i'm using:

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7976         569        7251           0         155        7195
Swap:          1970        1009         961
```

```
lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           2
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               26
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v4 @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:            4
CPU MHz:             2394.455
BogoMIPS:            4788.91
Hypervisor vendor:   VMware
Virtualization type: full
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            35840K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer hypervisor lahf_lm pti tsc_adjust ibpb ibrs stibp arat arch_capabilities
```

Is there any other parameters than JVM memory and Threads to tweak for improving the performances of NiFi ?

Comment: I have same question when sync data with mysql, nifi takes 7 minutes to sync 5000 rows, too slow I think, if you have find solution please tell me. My question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166048/how-to-improve-nifi-performance-when-sync-data-in-mysql

Comment: Ok, i'll let you know if there are some updates :)

Comment: We would probably need to see your flow, or at least a description of each processor being used from beginning up to PublishKafka. Also, generally you typically wouldn't set the concurrent tasks on a processor up to 1024, probably something like 8 or 16 would be a lot. The concurrent tasks are also bound by the timer driven thread pool which is configured from the top-right menu, and the number of threads in the timer driven thread pool should typically be a multiple of the number of cores, maybe 4 or 6 x the number of cores.

Comment: Hello again, i managed to increase performance of nifi using Java 8 Tuning by increasing  the code cache size. Add the following lines in boostrap configuration:

java.arg.7=-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m (change the value depending on your requirements)
java.arg.8=-XX:CodeCacheFlushingMinimumFreeSpace=10m
java.arg.9=-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
For more infos see: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/7882/hdfnifi-best-practices-for-setting-up-a-high-perfo.html

Comment: The following link https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z5sE.png  shows the processors used in the flow. I still have problem even after the java tuning !!!!!

Comment: How many total threads do you have in nifi?

Answer (score 2):

I think 6g for the heap is way too much for a 8g server. Keep space for the non heap memory of java, and for OS.

1024 threads is too much either. You only have 4 cores.

It seems you have configured the queue size, but having a really huge one make the system slow.

I would try to reduce to 4g the memory, 16 threads (in the processor AND in the Maximum timer driven thread count  & Maximum event driven thread count ).

To increase performances, I would try:
- merge records from OPC (by 1000 for example)
- use record bases kafka publishers to consume 1 message of 1000 OPC messages and push messages based on record writer

Maybe put bigger messages in kafka (not higher than 1MB) and split the message on the consumer side.

Hope this helps